# altering paths inside serverless artifact

Tags: node.js, lambda, serverless-framework

My "topology" is as:

```
-- /config/
-- /config/conf1/stage1/config.cfg
-- /config/conf1/stage2/config.cfg
-- /config/conf2/stage1/config.cfg
-- /config/conf2/stage2/config.cfg
-- /lib/
...
-- app.js
-- lambda_function_one.js
-- lambda_function_two.js
   ...
-- config.cfg
```

I have a project that is perfect for serverless - node/lambda. Managed to setup stages and configurations, as needed with one exception.

We use config.cfg in project root for local testing with app.js and config files inside the stages, for those respectful configurations.

One way to do this, is to move local configuration into another file, then use a shell script to copy the target config into the project root before packaging.

Would it be possible to specify paths so that serverless takes config.cfg from the directory where one is located and packages it into the "project root" somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [serverless-plugin-write-env-vars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-write-env-vars). This plugin will create a `.env` file upon deployment with configurations you specify in `serverless.yml`. You can still keep your [configuration in separate files](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-variables-in-other-files) (`.yml` or `.json`) and refer to them from `serverless.yml`.

For example:

Let's say `/config/conf1/stage1/config.yml` consist of:

```
# config.yml

url: https://foo.com
```

You can refer to it from `serverless.yml`:

```
# serverless.yml

custom:
  myStage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  writeEnvVars:
    MY_URL: ${file(./config/conf1/${self:custom.myStage}/config.yml):url}

plugins:
   - serverless-plugin-write-env-vars
```

For local testing you'll need to have a script to create the `.env` file yourself. A python example:

```
# test.py

import os.path
import sys
import shutil

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(here, ".."))


def before():
    # copy temp .env to root folder
    dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '.env_stub')
    global temp_file_path
    temp_file_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.pardir, '.env'))
    print('Creating ' + temp_file_path + '...')
    shutil.copyfile(dotenv_path, temp_file_path)


def after():
    # remove temp .env from root folder
    print('Removing ' + temp_file_path + '...')
    os.remove(temp_file_path)


temp_file_path = None
before()    
# test ...
after()
```

Comment: This is what I currently have, more or less. My preference is not have to do this. Hence, the question.

Comment: Then I might have misunderstood your question. Can you elaborate? Where is your `serverless.yml` located?

Comment: I have serverless.yml in the main directory, plus two individual config files for the two "services." My preference is custom pack the zip, as opposed to copying configs or building out the path inside lambda.

Comment: My suggestion above doesn't require you to copy configs or building the path from the lambda. Once .env is created and loaded using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) you can read the configuration using `process.env`